# How to change the sms verification template in firebase phone auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

in console firebase, in the menu Authentification -> Templates

There is a sms verification template :

```
%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code.
```

How to change this message template?

Comment: simply, you can't

Comment: I think your question seems like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692850/firebase-sms-verification-change-sender-name/55701849

Comment: @IntanDewani I'm asking this at 2017 while your link is in 2019, so I think you should comment on that link instead  :)

Answer (score 62):

*firebaser here*

Neither the email verification template nor the SMS verification template can be modified.  You can [select the language from the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/emails), however this is a per project setting and you can't modify the templates.

We understand that changing the template would allow you to tweak the user-experience of your app, but we don't allow this to prevent abuse of the service.

Comment: **Moderator note**: comments are not the place to ask a developer for a feature request. Comments are meant to for ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Anything else will be removed.

Answer (score 53):

Update 1 year later, still a no go, but I received this back from support

> The Firebase SMS Authentication message content will depend on the
>   platform you are requesting that message from. Here is a list of the
>   possible variations you may get:
>
> - **iOS and Android** - The SMS messages draw the app's name from the App Store / Play Store. One an app is published, the correct name
>     should start appearing. There may be a small delay (a week or two at
>     most).
> - **Web** - It will always use the domain that the SMS is requested from. To modify it, you can setup a custom domain.
> - **iOS (using Recaptcha)** - Phone authentication on iOS will show the project's url instead of the app's name in the verification
>     SMS when    using the reCAPTCHA flow. This is expected behavior. The
>     reCAPTCHA    flow was added for cases where an APNS token is not
>     available    (including on real devices). If APNS is not correctly
>     configured, a    real device will default to the reCAPTCHA flow.
>
> Unfortunately, neither the email verification template nor the SMS
>   verification template can be modified. You can select the language
>   from the Firebase Console, however this is a per project setting and
>   you can't modify the templates.
>
> We understand that changing the template would allow you to tweak the
>   user-experience of your app, but we don't allow this to prevent abuse
>   of the service. I hope this clears your consults about this topic. If
>   you happen to have any more questions, please, do not hesitate to
>   write back!

Comment: How do you opt out of using the reCaptcha? I cant have my firebase url exposed in the first text a user gets!? Google what are you thinking!?

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile you cannot change the content of the message, you can change the app's URL mentioned in the SMS.

1. Go to `Authentication > Sign-in Method > Authorized domains` and add your own domain `website.tld`
2. Now edit the Firebase config object (in your source code) and update the `authDomain` key to the domain you linked earlier.

Send a new test message, you're good to go.

Comment: where to find the authDomain key?

Comment: @soorya within the app you’re developing. Somehwre in there you have copied the firebase config, which also contains the authDomain key.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Firebase Support](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?hl=en) the %APP_NAME% should be shown in your firebase settings wherein the %APP_NAME% is called after *Public-facing name* in public settings.

EDIT:

I checked first where is the location of "localhost" and wherein i found on "Authentication>Sign-in method" then under 'authorized domain' you will find "localhost" in order to change the localhost you need to add a new domain.

Note:
be careful on deleting localhost to your authorized domain. It will take time to function OTP request.

Answer (score 0):

This one helps;
Go to Authentication > Sign-in Method > Authorized domains and add your own domain website.tld

Now edit the Firebase config object (in your source code) and update the authDomain key to the domain you linked earlier.

Comment: In official firebase documents, they have not mentioned changing SMS templates, so this is not possible to change.