# Firebase Phone Authentication message not coming properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

after coming message not show my project mane,
please help me,
I want to change this message %LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.
and make a custom message[image]

Comment: you ( or anyone) cannot change that text

Comment: but sir I want to add custom SMS for Phone Authentication message. It is possible or not

Comment: no it is not possible, you can change the language though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the sms verification template in firebase phone auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879218/how-to-change-the-sms-verification-template-in-firebase-phone-auth)

Comment: check the duplicate(link above)