# Is it possible to change the sms verification message of Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Android app several languages uses sms verification from firebase.

In the app several languages can be selected in order to set the app in the selected language.

It would be a nice bonus if it where possible to, apart from making the request to firebase, pass to it a parameter that depending on it would return a sms in the same language that this parameter indicates.

But I cannot even find any reference to start with, it seems non-existent.

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: Possibly your answer is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44879218/5689605

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go in **Authentication** in the Firebase console you'll see this:
[image]

Here you can see the template for the SMS message sent, including templates for different languages. The locale will be decided by the sdk in the user's phone. As per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth):

> The SMS message sent by Firebase can also be localized by specifying
>   the auth language via the setLanguageCode method on your Auth
>   instance.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setLanguageCode("fr");
```

This is also valid for the email messages.