# Firebase SMS Verification change sender name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Phone Auth to identify the user, the sms is received but I need to change the SMS sender name (Not the template) in mobile, is there anyway to change the sender name or the messaging service?
The sms is received like:

`Phonecode
106109 is your verification code for MyAppName`

what I need is:

`MyAppName
106109 is your verification code MyAppName`

Comment: you cannot do that with `firebase` try using some other `sms gateway`

Comment: @Swati correct. It's not possible as for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the sms verification template in firebase phone auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879218/how-to-change-the-sms-verification-template-in-firebase-phone-auth)

Comment: @Anddever it's not the same issue, I need to change the sender name not the template.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the response I got from Firebase support team as of March 19, 2021.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

As for now, We simply **can't change the template nor sender name/number.** We can only **see** in which template user will get SMS.

[image]

Additional Info:

- Until your app gets live, your format will be ***%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code.**
- After upload app on google-play-store, format will be **%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.**

Comment: I'm not trying to change the template, I need to change the SMS sender name not the content of the SMS

Comment: @KhalidTaha, Unfortunately that is not possible as I already noted in my answer.

Comment: @RumitPatel how to make it go live ?

Comment: @ĐứcBùi The message will be the same in debug as well as live.

Comment: The %APP_NAME% is not replaced with the app name from playstore  and is written as abc.firebaseapp.com..Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: @Xualakhawlhring , After live on play-store, it'll work as expected.

Answer (score 13):

the app name displayed in the SMS can't be changed manually (neither can you modify the template).
**The app name is retrieved from the play store/app store once the app is live in the store**.
This wasn't 100% clear to me after reading Rumit's answer.

here is the response from the firebase support about this matter:

> The SMS messages draw the app's name from the App Store / Play Store.
> Once an app is published, the correct name should start appearing.
> There may be a small delay (a week or two at most). So, this is an
> expected behavior if you published the app a few days ago.
>
> But if the app is published and you are still not able to see the
> app's name, it's possible that someone else has registered the user's
> App's Application ID (Usually the same as the Package Name - for
> instance, com.example.myapp) on the Play Store with a different name
> (which is the name shown as the %APP_NAME% value on the SMS template).
> Firebase pulls %APP_NAME% from the Play Store based on this
> Application ID.
>
> Since Application IDs in Google Play must be unique, you can't use an
> ID that is already taken by someone else.
>
> To fix this, you can change your Application ID and register the new
> one in the package name field in the Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0):

hi am also using firebase messages for send otp on mobile numbers. I also want to show my app name in text message but there is a firebase document that you can't change body of message in firebase. You can select the language from the Firebase console, however this is a per project setting and you can't modify the templates.

Comment: check [my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55701849/2289835) Your app. name will be displayed after getting live on google-play-store.

Answer (score -4):

Go to Firebase>Authentication>Templates>Password Reset> Put %APP_NAME%

Comment: This is for password reset not for the sms, I mean the sms sender name.

Comment: I don't think it's possible since templates for SMS verification is not changeable.