# MFA SMS Verification Template APP_NAME

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere in Google's documentation. But **where can I change the "APP_NAME" token in the SMS Verification template for the Google Identity MFA?**

The template is: `%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.`

The only place I can find a box for "App Name" is the "OAuth Consent Screen" in the credentials menu... But changing that does nothing to the template. Right now I been getting the URL of the app as a value for the APP_NAME token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to edit the %APP_NAME% present in the template in Firebase Authentication in the console. But if you are using an android or iOS app, you can edit the Application name in your code, as shown in this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set_the_application_id) for an android app and register the same in package name field in the Firebase console, as the name is drawn by Firebase from the Playstore. Also remember that the Application name must be unique in the playstore.

I have also found few Stackoverflow answers which you may wanna look at: [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65339590/15774177),  [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52525587/15774177)

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for replying!