# How to customize the SMS message template in Firebase Phone Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms, sms-gateway

I'm using Firebase Phone Authentication for my app's login functionality, and I would like to customize the SMS message template that is sent to users for phone number verification. By default, Firebase includes placeholders like "%**LOGIN_CODE**%" and "**%APP_NAME**%" in the SMS message template.

How can I customize the SMS message template in Firebase Phone Authentication and change the default placeholders? I want to provide a more personalized message to my users.

I have already checked the Firebase documentation but couldn't find any specific details on how to customize the SMS message template.

Any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this customization would be greatly appreciated.

I have gone through the Firebase documentation and explored the Firebase console, but I couldn't find any specific details on how to customize the SMS message template.

I would like to provide a more personalized message to my users by customizing the SMS message template and changing the default placeholders to include relevant information specific to my app. I want to understand the steps or API calls required to achieve this customization.

Any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this customization would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The templates used by Firebase Authentication cannot be modified beyond the variables you already identified, as that would make the product (even more) susceptible to be used for spamming.

If you want to deliver personalized messages, you will have to implement your own flow for that with a provider such as Twilio for sending the messages.

Also see:

- [How to change the sms verification template in firebase phone auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879218/how-to-change-the-sms-verification-template-in-firebase-phone-auth)
- [MFA SMS Verification Template APP_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319681/mfa-sms-verification-template-app-name)