# Firebase mobile SMS verification - Broken encoding

Tags: android, firebase, encoding, sms, verification

We have implemented phone line verification in Android and iOS using firebase, but **the received SMS message seems to have encoding problems** (the accented characters arrive broken).

In the firebase console, under "authentication/templates/SMS verification/ template language) the configured language template is SPANISH.

[image: firebase configuration]

So the message template to send is:

```
%LOGIN_CODE% es tu código de verificación para %APP_NAME%.
```

But the received message in the SMS says:

```
<the code> es tu c?digo de verificaci?n para <app name>
```

It seems to be a firebase bug, but I'm asking here to see if anyone knows how to fix this issue.

While not ideal, if I could send the message without accents, it could be a trade-off solution, but as it is said on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879218/how-to-change-the-sms-verification-template-in-firebase-phone-auth), the template can not be changed.

**How to fix this?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the same in Colombia. They are replacing 'special' characters to ensure the SMS encoding remains 7-bit (I think). This may vary by the local SMS provider firebase use. The simplest solution would be for Firebase to pre-replace the special characters with non-accented equivalents. This gives a bit of background on encoding: https://messente.com/documentation/tools/sms-length-calculator