# Firebase phone auth sms not using app name from playstore

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've made an app with Flutter Firebase and released to Google playstore about 2 months ago and till today,the verification SMS sent to user's phone isn't picking up the app name from the playstore. The SMS received is given as example below

> 111111 is your verification code for myproject465.firebaseapp.com

Another user got responded by firebase support [here][1] stating that the %APP_NAME% will be automatically used after release(small delay may occur) but it's been more than a month and still not picking up the app name.

I've contacted firebase support but as I'm unable to opt in for a paid tech support, they can't help me further. Hope someone here can help me out

UPDATED: Enabling Safety net in the project fixed the issue for me( auth domain update not done)
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52525587/7610087

Comment: What `authDomain` are you using in your code?

Comment: Default authDomain, do I need to change it?

Comment: Validate an app Domain, obtain a key for that, and use that `authDomain` in your code.