# How to change the Firebase phone verification content

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52525587/12716363

They said:

> iOS and Android - The SMS messages draw the app's name from the App Store / Play Store. One an app is published, the correct name
> should start appearing. There may be a small delay (a week or two at most).

My app has lived a few months but our SMS messages are still: `Your firebase app verification code is ...`

I tried setting `Firebase -> Project settings -> Environment type` to `Production`
and changing `Public-facing name` still does not work.

Comment: I also have the same issue. "Your Firebase App Verification Code is" but in the firebase app SMS template it says Message will be "%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%."  but I don't see the latter only the former